# Set Maximum cpu qemu/libvirt almalinux

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu

I want ask to increase supported CPU core on qemu kvm. When I creating new VM I see error like below

> error: internal error: QEMU unexpectedly closed the monitor (vm='ID'):
> qemu-system-x86_64: -accel kvm: warning: Number of hotpluggable cpus
> requested (128) exceeds the recommended cpus supported by KVM (32).

What command or step to increase total cpus supported by kvm?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the qemu's option `maxcpus`. See the [Qemu's Virtual CPU hotplug](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/cpu-hotplug.html) doc.

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -display none -no-user-config -m 2048 \
  -nodefaults -monitor stdio -machine pc,accel=kvm,usb=off \
  -smp 1,maxcpus=2 -cpu IvyBridge-IBRS \
  -qmp unix:/tmp/qmp-sock,server=on,wait=off
```